# Can I define my own binary operators in Ada?

Tags: ada

I am creating a package in Ada and I am wondering if it's possible to create my own binary operators not define standard ones. Like

```
function "sim"(L,R : matrix) returns boolean;
```

which checks if the two matrices are similar.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ada allows you to override operators but you cannot invent new operators. On the other hand you can create new functions as you like.